# ¿Cómo Ordenar una Matriz 20x4 Indicando un Índice "n"?

Tags: java

Teniendo una matriz resultado:

```
double [][] matrizResultado = {{1, -2, 1, 9}, {2, 0, 4, 28}, {3, 2, -3, -25}, {4, -4, -3, -25}, {5, -5, -1, -8}, {6, 3, -3, -30}, {7, -2, 1, 7}, {8, 2, 4, 26}, {9, -1, -1, -10}, {10, 2, -2, -20}, {11, 14, 3, 20}, {12, 1, 0, 0}, {13, 2, 3, 20}, {14, 3, 1, 8}, {15, 3, 5, 33}, {16, -4, -4, -40}, {17, -7, -2, -20}, {18, -2, 3, 21}, {19, -3, 1, 7}, {20, -1, 1, 8}};
```

Donde:

[i][0] = Puntos de Asignación.

[i][1] = Entregas.

[i][2] = Tiempo.

[i][3] = Eficiencia.

Debo ordenar la matriz de tres formas diferentes para dar respuesta a tres solicitudes de información.

1. Ordenar la matriz por la columna [i][2] de tiempo, de menor a mayor, indicando los tres Putos de Asignación ([i][0]) con menores tiempos. Debería dar una salida así:

   Los puntos con mayores demoras de tiempo: Punto 16 = -4, Punto 3 = -3, Punto 4 = -3
2. Ordenar la matriz por la columna [i][1] de entregas, de menor a mayor, indicando los tres Putos de Asignación ([i][0]) con menores entregas. Debería dar una salida así:

   Los puntos con mayores sobre-entregas: Punto 17 = -7, Punto 5 = -5, Punto 4 = -4
3. Ordenar la matriz por las columnas [i][1] y [i][2], de menor a mayor, indicando los cinco Putos de Asignación ([i][0]) donde ambos datos son negativos. Debería dar una salida así:

   Los puntos donde pasan ambas: Punto 4, Punto 5, Punto 9, Punto 16, Punto 17

He logrado ordenar las columnas de "tiempo" y "entregas" individualmente con los siguientes códigos:

```
public static void ordenarTiempo(double lista[][]){
        for(int i=0;i<(lista.length-1);i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<lista.length;j++){
                if(lista[i][2]>lista[j][2]){
                    //Intercambiamos valores
                    double variableauxiliar=lista[i][2];
                    lista[i][2]=lista[j][2];
                    lista[j][2]=variableauxiliar;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void ordenarEntregas(double lista[][]){
        for(int i=0;i<(lista.length-1);i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<lista.length;j++){
                if(lista[i][1]>lista[j][1]){
                    //Intercambiamos valores
                    double variableauxiliar=lista[i][1];
                    lista[i][1]=lista[j][1];
                    lista[j][1]=variableauxiliar;
                }
            }
        }
```

Este código solo me permite ordenar el contenido de las columnas [i][1] y [i][2] respectivamente, pero no me ordena las demás, es decir si ordeno [i][1] las demás continúan con el orden inicial, lo mismo pasa si ordeno [i][2]. Además, no tengo idea de como indicarle a Java que me imprima los tres primeros resultados como se solicita. me ha tocado de la siguiente manera:

```
    TransporteCamion.ordenarTiempo(matrizResultado);

    System.out.println("Los puntos con mayores demoras de tiempo = Punto "+ Math.round(matrizResultado[15][0] * 10) / 10 + " = " + Math.round(matrizResultado[0][2] * 10) / 10 + "," 
    + " Punto "+ Math.round(matrizResultado[2][0] * 10) / 10 + " = " + Math.round(matrizResultado[1][2] * 10) / 10 + ","
    + " Punto "+ Math.round(matrizResultado[3][0] * 10) / 10 + " = " + Math.round(matrizResultado[2][2] * 10) / 10);
```

Lo mismo ocurre con entregas:

```
        TransporteCamion.ordenarEntregas(matrizResultado);

        System.out.println("Los puntos con mayores sobre-entregas = Punto "+ Math.round(matrizResultado[16][0] * 10) / 10 + " = " + Math.round(matrizResultado[0][1] * 10) / 10 + "," 
        + " Punto "+ Math.round(matrizResultado[4][0] * 10) / 10 + " = " + Math.round(matrizResultado[1][1] * 10) / 10 + ","
        + " Punto "+ Math.round(matrizResultado[3][0] * 10) / 10 + " = " + Math.round(matrizResultado[2][1] * 10) / 10);
```

¿Cómo puedo ordenas la columna "tiempo" y que me ordene el resto de la matriz basándose en ella y que además me permita imprimir los tres primeros resultados de menor a mayor en ese ordenamiento?

¿Cómo puedo ordenas la columna "entregas" y que me ordene el resto de la matriz basándose en ella y que además me permita imprimir los tres primeros resultados de menor a mayor en ese ordenamiento?

¿Cómo puedo ordenas las dos columnas al mismo tiempo y que me ordene el resto de la matriz basándose en ellas y que además me permita imprimir los cinco primeros resultados donde ambas columnas tengan los resultados negativos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las posiciones de los elementos en las sub matrices no deben cambiarse. Solo se deben cambiar de posición las sub matrices completas tomando como referencia el índice especificado. Ejemplo:

```
matrizResultado = {{2, 0, 4, 28}, {1, -2, 1, 9}}
```

Si se quiere ordenar la matriz por entregas `[i][1]`, la matriz quedaría así:

```
matrizResultado = {{1, -2, 1, 9}, {2, 0, 4, 28}}
```

Como se puede ver se cambia el orden de las sub matrices pero no sus valores internos.

Con esa idea se puede hacer una función de ordenamiento que reciba el índice por el cual se desea ordenar la matriz y llamarla por cada ordenamiento que se desea hacer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] matrizResultado = {{1, -2, 1, 9}, {2, 0, 4, 28}, {3, 2, -3, -25}, {4, -4, -3, -25}, {5, -5, -1, -8}, {6, 3, -3, -30}, {7, -2, 1, 7}, {8, 2, 4, 26}, {9, -1, -1, -10}, {10, 2, -2, -20}, {11, 14, 3, 20}, {12, 1, 0, 0}, {13, 2, 3, 20}, {14, 3, 1, 8}, {15, 3, 5, 33}, {16, -4, -4, -40}, {17, -7, -2, -20}, {18, -2, 3, 21}, {19, -3, 1, 7}, {20, -1, 1, 8}};

     // procesar por entregas
     procesarPorIndice(matrizResultado, 1);
     // procesar por tiempo
     procesarPorIndice(matrizResultado, 2);
     // procesar por eficiencia
     procesarPorIndice(matrizResultado, 3);


}

public static void procesarPorIndice(int[][] matriz, final int index) {
    // ordenar el arreglo por el índice dado
    Arrays.sort(matriz, Comparator.comparingDouble(o -> o[index]));

    // mostrar los primeros 3 resultados
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print(String.format("Punto %d = %d ", matriz[i][0],matriz[i][2]));
    }
    System.out.println();

}

Salida:

Punto 17 = -2 Punto 5 = -1 Punto 4 = -3 
Punto 16 = -4 Punto 4 = -3 Punto 3 = -3 
Punto 16 = -4 Punto 6 = -3 Punto 4 = -3
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Lobos, me das luz para resolverlo.